# React Native with Realm - Removing from iCloud Backup

Tags: react-native, realm, icloud

Apple have rejected my app because:

```
On launch and content download, your app stores 6.81MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.
```

The app was created with React Native 29, and Realm JS.

The Realm file appears to be stored in the Documents folder by default:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD64434C-6761-4760-93C4-57C62438B89C/Documents/default.realm
```

I've since moved the Realm files default location using:

```
Realm.defaultPath = Realm.defaultPath.replace("Documents", "Library/Caches/" + AppConstants.packageName + "/realm")
```

And the path is now:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD64434C-6761-4760-93C4-57C62438B89C/Library/Caches/<NameSpace>/data/default.realm
```

However Apple still reject the app for the same reason. They suggest using NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey . How would I do this?

Comment: By any chance did you work out a way to overcome this problem? If you could share some sample code, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) explaining how to use the api. Things are a bit difficult as the file needs to exist before you can make this api call, and the Realm file doesn't get created until you run your RN code, which makes it difficult to do this in `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`. One think you could do is to create an empty Realm file, copying it to the expected path, and then making this api call at app launch. Alternatively you could try calling into a native module which flags the file after you open the Realm, but that seems more difficult.

Comment: Has anyone done this? Do we have any sample for RN? or may be an API for using?